# Unable to compile with GNU Emacs

Tags: emacs, compile

I'm trying to use GNU Emacs to write small programs. I use the compile command `make -k` but i always get the message

```
make -k 
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I've tried installing MinGW and modifying the path of my environment variables and a lot of other things but it does not work.

Comment: Since you talk about MinGW I assume you are on MS windows. Its not easy to compile emacs on windows(atleast for a beginner). Its better to use precomipiled binaries. you can get it [here](http://alpha.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/windows/). go to the end of the page to get latest version

Comment: After you change the environment variable PATH to include the 'c:\path\to\mingw\bin' which includes the 'make' program, restart emacs and give it another go. Also. You *could* evaluate `(setenv "PATH" (concat "c:\path\to\mingw\bin;" (getenv "PATH")))' from the scratch to remove the need to restart emacs. If this comment solves your problem I will turn it into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

First verify that you a DOS window can find the make command. This will verify if it is in your `PATH` environment variable and also installed.

Then, once you know that it is working but still not working from inside of emacs check the values of `PATH` that emacs is seeing by evaluating `(getenv "PATH")` in the scratch buffer or via `M-:`. Also check the value of the `exec-path` variable.

Any problems with any of the above could cause your problem.